# Bootstrap - Edit input alert unfilled information?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if there was a way to customize these alerts in bootstrap?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are browser based. If can create your own if toy really want

Comment: @AustinPerez you don't have to thanks on stackoverflow. Just mark my response as answer or vote it up if it helped you